# Where to update GitHub Personal Access Token (lost token) to be able to push changes?

Tags: git

My first app pushed via Pythonanywhere, so I might be struggling with basic here. I successfully cloned the app from my github repository, using Personal Access Token etc. All worked well, until I lost the PAT.

Now, I would like to push changes made on Pythonanywhere repo, back to GitHub, of course, while using I was asked for the PAT.

Had to regenerate token as per *'If you’ve lost or forgotten this token, you can regenerate it, but be aware that any scripts or applications using this token will need to be updated.'*

Then, I `git clone https://github.com/XXXX/XXXX.git` for the same repo, username and new PAT. Which I believe was a mistake.

Now got changes to be committed, but push won't work as I get *Everything up-to-date* but if I run `git status` I see changes ready to be committed.

What should it change? Or how to update my webapp with the new token? (.gitconfig?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now got changes to be committed, but push won't work as I get Everything up-to-date but if I run git status I see changes ready to be committed.

This has nothing to do with Python or GitHub (at least not yet, not as of *this* problem).  It happens because `git push` pushes *commits*.  It does not push changes, nor (directly) files.

If `git status` shows `changes to be committed`, you have done things in your *working tree*—which is not actually *in* Git yet—and then you have run `git add` to prepare whatever you did so be committed (so that it's sort of halfway into Git now).  Run `git commit`, [write a good commit message](https://reflectoring.io/meaningful-commit-messages/) in your chosen editor, and let the commit finish.  You have now added a new commit to your Git repository!

*Now* you can `git push` the new commit.  Run `git push` or `git push -u origin branch` or similar to *send* the commit to *another* Git repository.  What `git push` does is contact some other Git software, using a URL.  The URL is stored under the short name `origin` (or some other short name, but `origin` is the usual first one, and often the only one, so `origin` is almost always the *right* one).

Once your Git software is talking to the other Git software, the two Git implementations look into their two—different, but presumably closely related at this point—repositories.  *Your* repository will typically have some commit(s) that they lack.  Your Git software and their Git software will use the *branch name* you provided here, if you provided one, to figure out which commits those are.  If you omit the branch name, as in `git push` with no additional arguments, your Git software uses your *current* branch name—the one you selected earlier when you chose to begin working—to figure out which commits those are, as if you used the current branch name in your `git push` (and the name `origin`, if you left that out, is also implied).

Having figured out which commits you have, but they lack, *your* Git software now packages up those commits and their files.  Git is quite clever here, often sending only *differences* to files.  Every commit stores a *full copy of every file* (in a rather magical format that eliminates data duplication), but during this communications phase, your Git has learned about the commits that *their* Git already has, and uses that information to be able to figure out what data they can re-use, and what new stuff they actually need.  (This makes use of the same magic that eliminates duplication *within* a repository, but this time uses it across two separate, individual repositories.)

Having sent the commits that they lack, your Git—your software, working with your repository—now politely requests that *their* Git add those commits to a branch in their repository that has the same name as the branch you selected in your repository.  There are forms of `git push` that use different names on each side, but we have not used this form here.

If:

- they *like* your commit, *and*
- any add-ons that the hosting provider (e.g., GitHub) have added on *permit* this action,

*then* (and only then) they'll accept this `git push` and update *their* repository to hold the new commits.

The access-granting extensions that GitHub and other hosting providers add on are where tokens (PATs and the like) come in.  If you can't get into GitHub at all, or if you don't have permissions at this point, *now* you've reached the problem you thought you had earlier.

Comment: This is much appreciated @torek. So the question I have is if you can help (for the future), once my PAT token expires on GitHub, and I re-generate a new one, will this have further implications? meaning, what steps do I need to make, to make sure it all works fine when asked for the username & token while pushing on my app? (with a re-generated token)

Comment: @Jonasz: If you have a cached copy of the token, you'll need to instruct whatever's caching it to toss the cached copy. The complication here is that this is up to the particular credential helper you're using. A really smart one might be able to figure out that it has expired on its own, but most probably aren't that smart.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to resolve this using `git reset --hard @{u}` and discard all local commits on this branch.

All changes are now made only locally and pushed, next on Pythonanywhere app only `git pull` with new PAT - lessons learned.